# What is this device? What is it used for?

Tags: identification, debugging, test-equipment

I found this while going through some things at my grandpa's house. I believe it is used for residential wiring, but I'm not entirely sure.

It resembles a pen. The tip is spring loaded with a very sharp pin, almost as if to be used on a PCB for contact tracing or continuity checking.

It also has branding on it with the name "FEDTRO" that is the same logo as here [FEDTRO logo reference (link might vanish)](https://mickeymantle7.net/wp-content/gallery/fedtro-ads/manfed036.jpg).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: does it open? . .

Comment: does it have a socket on the non-pointy end?

Comment: Since it (apparently) has only *one* electrical contact I suspect it is an AC voltage detector for residential wiring, somewhat like [this one](https://www.harborfreight.com/non-contact-voltage-tester-63919.html). Modern ones are purely non-contact (i.e. even the one "connection" is plastic and works if you just hold it near a live wire), but perhaps the older ones used an actual metal connection at the business end?

Comment: @jsotola it does not open that I can tell, I've tried and it didn't unscrew or anything and i didn't want to force it as not to break it

Comment: @Neil_UK it doesn't have any socket on the non-pointy end that I can tell. The non pointy side is flat and shows that "FEDTRO" logo

Comment: @Mr.Snrub that sounds like a really good idea and fits the description of that harbor freight tool. Thanks!

Comment: If nothing else, I've learned Mickey Mantle was their major spokesperson...(!)

Comment: Try posting the same question to some antique radio forums.

Comment: Could it be a neon mains voltage tester? Perhaps the metal logo is meant to be contacting your body (the return path) and you pierce the insulation of the wire to test if it's live.

Comment: If it does not open then you can't put batteries in it. Therefore it works by absorbing either EM waves (most likely) or light (unlikely). Try putting this near an insulated cable carrying mains voltage. Do not pierce anything yet. You always have an ac power supply, Start at low voltages.

Answer (score 3):

I just came across this post! It is a spark plug tester.

Comment: Hmm... some more details please?

Comment: Spark plugs are very common in cars but are used in other devices.

Comment: I have the instruction sheet I tried to send a picture of it

Comment: @DarrinDeBellis can you upload to google drive or something and provide the link?